# Two Get methods without parameters in a single controller in ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to include two Get methods with different names but without any input parameters in a single controller in ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API?

For example, I want to have two GetBookXXX methods – one returning a list with only the book titles and the other returning a list with all book details (title, author, ISBN, etc). The approach I have seen so far is to use two separate controllers, but I would prefer to have a single one and not duplicating the plumbing code twice.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you given it a try to see if it caused any issues?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api?rq=1) looks like the answer your looking for:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Define your methods as follows:

```
[ActionName("GetBookXXX")]
public ActionResult BookTitles()
{
    return View();   
}

[ActionName("GetBookXXX")]
public ActionResult BookDetails(int id)
{
    return View();   
}
```

See http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx for further reference.