# How to disable Chunked Transfer Encoding in ASP.Net C# using HttpClient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core

I'm trying to post some JSON to an external API which keeps failing because my content is chunked. Please can someone tell me how to disable it?

I'm using ASP.NET 5 so think I'm using System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.1.0

Here is the code I've tried:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    // TODO - Send HTTP requests
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("SAML", samlToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = false;

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, jsonObject);
}
```

But It still seems to have the Transfer-Encoding set to "chunked" when I check Fiddler.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: seems this bug? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30283

Answer (score 31):

It looks like you need to set the `Content-Length` header too, if you don't it seems to use the `MaxRequestContentBufferSize` on `HttpClientHandler` to chunk the data when sending it.

Try using a `StringContent`, `ByteArrayContent` or `StreamContent` (If the steam is seekable) as these will be able to calculate the length for you.

```
var content = new StringContent(json);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(content);
```

The `PostAsJsonAsync` extension methods create `ObjectContent` under the hood which doesn't calculate the `Content-Length` and return false:

```
public class ObjectContent : HttpContent
{
    /* snip */

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = -1L;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thus will always fall back to chunking to the buffer size.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use `JsonContent` in combination with `LoadIntoBufferAsync`, check out [this answer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30283#issuecomment-531517005).
Example:

```
var content = JsonContent.Create(someObject);
await content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PutAsync($"/endpoint", content);
```

Comment: This does NOT work if you use .PostAsJsonAsync(), instead of PutAsync()/PostAsync().  @kevin-smith pointed this out in his post.

Comment: This also does NOT work if you include `JsonContent` in `MultipartFormDataContent` in .NET 6

Comment: Yes, you can't use `PostAsJsonAsync()`. Instead you have to instantiate `JsonContent`, load the content to the buffer, and then pass it to `PostAsync()`.