# PostAsJsonAsync doesnt seem to post body parameters

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, rest, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Azure logic app that exposes a REST endpoint.

The following JSON body works fine when I call it through postman.

```
{
   "to": "ggtest@yahoo.com",
   "subject": "Hello there",
   "message": "Hello there!!!!!"
}
```

I'm able to see the incoming request formed nicely

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
        "Host": "maskedout.northcentralus.logic.azure.com:443",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/6.4.1",
        "Content-Length": "99",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "to": "ggtest@yahoo.com",
        "subject": "Hello there",
        "message": "Hello there!!!!!"
    }
}
```

However, when I try to make the same call using C# PostAsJsonAsync with this code:

```
        var email = new Email
        {
            to = "gg@live.com.sg",
            subject = "from webapp",
            message = "hello world"
        };
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = "maskedout";
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<Email>(uri, email);
```

I'm able to call my REST endpoint successfully, but it does not contain the body

This is the incoming request I see:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Host": "maskedout.northcentralus.logic.azure.com",
        "x-ms-request-root-id": "9e5513c2-43961642a3688718",
        "x-ms-request-id": "|9e5513c2-43961642a3688718.1.",
        "Request-Id": "|9e5513c2-43961642a3688718.1.1.",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length": "0"
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? What's different in my C# code compared to postman?

Comment: have you called the json serializer you are using to verify the json is getting serialized correctly?  looks like you are using SSL in the postman request, but not in your code.  Also what's with the chunked encoding.

Comment: looks similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464233/how-to-disable-chunked-transfer-encoding-in-asp-net-c-sharp-using-httpclient  Have you tried posting it without the PostAsJsonAsync extension method?

Comment: I'm not sure what's with the chunked encoding. As you can see from my C# code, I'm not doing much except just calling PostJsonAsAsync and passing in my object

Comment: So have you tried it without PostAsJsonAsync.  ie.  serializing the object and setting up all the headers by hand?

Answer (score 12):

I've just run into this problem too. The issue appears to be the `Content-Length` header. In Postman it is the length of the content but using HttpClient the length is 0 so I am guessing the endpoint is ignoring the body as it is being told it is empty.

I created my own extension to get around this:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonAsync<T>(
        this HttpClient client,
        string requestUri,
        T value)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        var content = new StringContent(data,
                                        Encoding.UTF8,
                                        MimeTypes.Json);
        Debug.WriteLine(client.BaseAddress + requestUri);
        return await client.PostAsync(requestUri,
                                      content)
                           .WithRequestTimeout()
                           .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: Where `MimeTypes.Json` are defined on?

Comment: @DanielSantos it could well be a static string for ( "application/json") that I added but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

the `TransferEncodingChunked` header property should be `false` by default.

However, try this:

```
        var email = new Email
        {
            to = "gg@live.com.sg",
            subject = "from webapp",
            message = "hello world"
        };
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = "maskedout";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = false;
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<Email>(uri, email);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. It seems that the `content-length` header is set to 0 when using the default `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method, which causes the server to ignore the request body.

My solution was to install the `System.Net.Http.Json` nuget package that uses the new `System.Text.Json` serializer.

When you add `using System.Net.Http.Json;`, you should be able to use the new extension method `PostAsJsonAsync` that works (sets the `content-length` header) properly.

```
namespace System.Net.Http.Json
{
    public static class HttpClientJsonExtensions
    {
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<TValue>(this HttpClient client, string? requestUri, TValue value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, value, null, cancellationToken);
        }

    }
}
```