# Ajax not passing array to Controller Action?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Iv searched related questions, but still not able to get this to work in my situation. I am working in ASP.NET MVC.

I have a report that has 3 filters. Only 1 value can be selected for Filters 1 and 2. My 3rd filter is a Multi Select filter. I load an array with all the values selected from the Multi Select Filter, then I want to pass all 3 Filters to my controller action. Filters 1 and 2 work correctly, but my Multi Select Filter is not being passed, and shows as Null in my Actions parameter.

Below is my JavaScript and Ajax call

```
$('#applyFilter').click(function () {

            var options = new Array();
            //Fill array with values from Multi Select Filter
            $('#treeFilter > option:selected').each(
                function (i) {
                    options[i] = $(this).text();
                })


            var filter1 =  $('#LOCFilterDropdown').val();
            var filter2 = $('#ESNFilterDropdown').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/FilterReport",

                data: {
                    filterOne: filter1,
                    filterTwo: filter2,
                    multiselectFilter: options
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#reportTable').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

The receiving Action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FilterReport(string filterOne,string filterTwo, int? page, List<string> multiselectFilter)
{
     //filterOne contains correct value
     //filterTwo contsins correct value
     //multiSelectFilter contains null

     //returns partial view

}
```

Can anyone tell me why my

```
List<string> multiselectFilter
//Iv also tried string[] multiselectFilter, but this didnt change anything
```

is now receiving the array from the ajax call?

Comment: what does your html look like

Comment: @pparas The html is fine I believe. I tested the array with Console.Log() to view the contents of the array. The array has the correct values inside it.

Comment: @pparas This is how I create the filter list, had to remove the @ in the razor sytax to post this comment. <select id="treeFilter" name="treeFilter" multiple="multiple">
           foreach (var row in Model.treeFilterValues)
            {
                <option value="row">row</option>
            }
        </select>

Comment: Hmm... Need a `JSON.stringify()` somewhere? Too much for a `GET` method? Is the data present in the request when it gets to the controller but not getting mapped correctly? Just thinking out loud...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send a complex object with GET method. The reason this is failing is that GET method can't have a body and all the values are being encoded into the URL.

Similar Question

[Complex type is getting null in a ApiController parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916340/complex-type-is-getting-null-in-a-apicontroller-parameter)

I Would just join the Multiselectfilter in client and split them in server side

```js
 multiselectFilter: options.join(',')
```

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FilterReport(string filterOne, string filterTwo, int? page, string multiselectFilter)
    {
        string[] array = multiselectFilter.Split(',');

        //returns partial view

    }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I also tried changing 'GET' to 'POST' based on your answer, and that works also.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to add these in your ajax call add:

```
dataType: "json",
traditional: true
```

If the options array can get big, I would use POST so that you avoid reaching the url max length limit.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stqafruq/). I think you might have an issue with the serialization. Although I am not a hundred percent sure. Here is the code to serialize `options = JSON.stringify(options);` , Like the previous answer has said.

Comment: thank you for the example. It was right that I cant use a complex object in a GET request.