# Web API GET method with two complex parameters

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, parameter-passing, get-method

I have a Web API program that has 8 get methods.

Each method can get 2 parameters - `filters` and `sorts`.

- `filters` - a json object that contains all the params you can filter by
- `sorts` - an array that contains all the properties you want to sort by

For example:

```
www.facebook.com/GetFriends?filters={name:"lior", color:{name:"blue", RGB:{255, 100, 0}}}&sorts=[{prop:"name", desc:true}, {prop:"age", desc:false}]
```

The api's only available from other servers, so there's no need to worry about URL characters limit in browsers.

We chose `GET` method because the purpose of this api is only to get data.

I'm not sure the url we require is in a 'normal' format-

Is that okay in a `GET` method to use a two query params that one of them is json and the other is array?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please try running your code before posting.

Comment: Using json as query string parameter value is truly a bad choice. First thing to consider: json must be encoded if put in the URI. I suggest you to flatten you objects and make them simple query strings key/value pairs. Avoid using JSON at all costs.

Comment: No, that will not work out of the box. If you have complex data you want to pass it would be better to change it to a POST method and except data from the message body instead of the uri. Then you could pass it as json. Alternatively you can write a bunch of code to force it to work the way you want but it is not worth the trouble or maintenance that follows when there is an easy alternative.

Comment: It works, but i'm asking for help to understand the standart.
I know i can use POST but my api purpose is only to get data, without inserting or updating.

Comment: Here you may find what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916340/complex-type-is-getting-null-in-a-apicontroller-parameter