# WebApi Routing to Action with Object Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to set up routing for a `Get` action that has an object as it's only parameter.

I have the following code:

```
public class LuteImage
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Dimensions { get; set; }
    public string Quality { get; set; }
}

public class ImageController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(LuteImage luteImage)
    {
    }
}
```

In my `WebApiConfig.cs` file I have the following route before the default route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ImageOptions",
    routeTemplate: "api/image/{id}/{dimensions}/{quality}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "image",
        dimensions = RouteParameter.Optional,
        quality = RouteParameter.Optional,
    }
);
```

However, when I navigate to `localhost:xxx/api/image/123/300x300/b`, the `luteImage` property is just `null`.

How do I allow the `luteImage` object to take the parameters?

Comment: uhh I highly doubt you can get a complex object across in a GET.  You could just accept the 3 parameters and build your object up, though.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I thought it would be possible, because as I understand it, doesn't normal MVC routing handle this just fine with `GET` requests? You simply pass the properties and the system handles the conversion to the complex object?

Comment: By using `[FromUri]` you can populate a complex object. It's all in the [proposed duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12916668/4949005). If you don't find your answer there, then please let me know and I'll write an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you @smoksnes. That's exactly what I needed. Do you know the StackOverflow best practice in closing this question?

Comment: @Ant - I think that you can accept it as a duplicate, if the proposed duplicate actually answers your question.

Comment: Hey look at that.  I did not know that was possible

Comment: @smoksnes thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project.