# how to receive Dictionary in WebAPI from javascript json

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have this controller function in WebAPI:

```
public class EntityController : APIController
{
       [Route("Get")]
       public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]Dictionary<string, string> dic)
       { ... }
}
```

and my request, in javascript, looks like this:

```
{
     "key1": "val1",
     "key2": "val2",
     "key3": "val3"
},
```

but the parse failed. is there a way to make this work without writing to much code? Thanks

my full request:

```
http://localhost/Exc/Get?dic={"key1":"val1"}
```

Comment: Since you post data as JSON body, shouldn't it be `[FromBody]`, not `[FromUri]`?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev i am using the GET method for this http request. so the parameters can be sent only through the url

Comment: Ok, I have misunderstood you. You can then check if your API can read this argument if you manually do request `/your-api/?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3`. If yes, then check what request is sent to your WebAPI by your JS in your browser Network tab.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev you split the JSON to it's values. i want to send the entire json to the server, and want to be serialized to Dictionary as described

Comment: What is your WebApi Root ?

Comment: @aelbouachri what do you mean by root? i published this service localhost through iis. the request reaches the destination. i can see that in debug. but the parse of "dic" failed.

Comment: Your WebApiConfig      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            ); . How you defiended it ?

Comment: @aelbouachri yea that is my config. it's the default one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom model binder:

```
public class DicModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (val == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string key = val.RawValue as string;
        if (key == null)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Wrong value type");
            return false;
        }

        string errorMessage;

        try
        {
            var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(key);
            bindingContext.Model = jsonObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            return true;
        }
        catch (JsonException e)
        {
            errorMessage = e.Message;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Cannot convert value: " + errorMessage);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
public class EntityController : APIController
{
    [Route("Get")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([ModelBinder(typeof(DicModelBinder))]Dictionary<string, string> dic)
    { ... }
}
```

In the ModelBinder I used the Newtonsoft.Json library to parse the input string, then converted it to Dictionary. You could implement a different parsing logic.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. your solution is working. but i want to ask, is that the simplest way to do that? should i use ModelBinder as best practice to handle this? isn't that simpler to receive this parameter as string, and parse it to Dictionary inside the controller?

Comment: You could do the parsing inside the controller, but then loose the ability to reuse your code. The ModelBinder is reusable and separates the parsing logic from the logic in the controller, which is a good thing. If someone is looking at your method then sees immediately what the parameter is and do not has to care about parsing etc.

Answer (score 0):

See here ... with some adaptations to make. I think your difficulties are in how to call the URL.

[Complex type is getting null in a ApiController parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916340/complex-type-is-getting-null-in-a-apicontroller-parameter)

Comment: That is not a complex type. Its a dictionary of strings. Its not helping me.