# How to pass model values in a parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass values using model as parameter.
This is basically the mvc web api app

**This is my Model class**

```
public class ConversionModel
{
    public double  value { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public double  result { get; set; }
    public string  from { get; set; }
    public string  to { get; set; }
}
```

**This is My controller code**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Conversion/Currency")]
public double Currency(ConversionModel c)
{
    return c.value;
}
```

**And my url is**

http://localhost:5267/api/Conversion/Currency?value=123

But is showing me an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you know what a `NullReferenceException` is?

Comment: do you send your Conversion model data when you call this Currency() action?

Comment: @hsnbl I just wanted to return 123 which I passed from url

Comment: @mason I know what NullReferenceException is

Comment: Can you try use this public double Currency(int? value)

Answer (score 0):

You are only providing an integer value, it cannot be converted to ConversionModel.

You can either use post

```
[HttpPost] 
public double Currency([FromBody]ConversionModel c)
```

which is more suitable for a complex object.

Or pass the values as separate get parameters, constructing a ConversionModel in the method body.

Or use get with [FromUri]; this still requires supplying all the individual parameter-values. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916340/complex-type-is-getting-null-in-a-apicontroller-parameter))

Passing a collection of individual values is a little fragile/clumsy, I would prefer to use post. Besides which, it is unlikely that you need all the values, and an instance of the class, if you will be simply returning a double value, so post is most likely to be appropriate.

Comment: so how can i pass the value, actually the value property in model is integer.

Comment: If you only want to pass the 'value', an integer, then declare the parameter as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an object in query string. You need to write all parameters in your Route annotation.

```
[Route("api/Conversion/Currency/{value}/{qty}/{result}/{from}/{to}")]
```

And then in your action:

```
public double Currency(double value, int qty, double result, string from, string to) {
    var conversionModel = new ConversionModel();
    conversionModel.value = value;
    conversionModel.qty = qty;
    conversionModel.result = result;
    conversionModel.from = from;
    conversionModel.to = to;

    // Rest of your code.
}
```