# Two HTTP Post method with different parameters in one Web API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement a Controller with more than one POST method in one controller. I have the following:

```
public class PatientController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Patient> All() { ... }

    [HttpGet]
    public Patient ByIndex(int index) { ... }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Add([FromBody]Patient patient) { ... }
}
```

And i have a this on my routing:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "API_1",
    "{controller}/{index}",
    new { index = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Everything works as expected :)

Now, i would like to add the following action:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("save")]
    public void Save(int not_used = -1) { ... }
```

Without adding anything to routing, i get the following error in to Fiddler: Multiple actions were found that match the request.

If i add this to my routing (as a second or first, doesn't matter):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "API_2",
    "{controller}/{action}/{not_used}",
    new { not_used = RouteParameter.Optional },
    new { action = "save|reset" }); // Action must be either save or reset
```

Ill get the same error in to Fiddler.

Is this even possible? Can i have more than one POST, with different (type) parameters, in one controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple HttpPost method in MVC4 Web API Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407267/multiple-httppost-method-in-mvc4-web-api-controller)

Comment: What URL are you calling?  Also, are you really not using the normal `/api` prefix in api URL's?

Comment: Yep, without api - the project doesn't contain MVC at all. When psoting im using the following POST localhost:6850/Patient/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have two methods: `Save` and `Add`, and both match your route `API_1`.  The fact that you have another route `API_2` that could have matched if the url had been a little different doesn't matter: you have two matching methods for *this* route.

You've got a few options:

1. Put the save method in a different controller, and for that controller always map action names.
2. Ensure that `Save` doesn't match the default route.  In particular, you've included an optional parameter in Save and that means it's OK to omit.  If the parameter were non-optional, it wouldn't match the route.
3. Change your architecture to use a message-based format; i.e. rather than distinguishing based on actions, simply pass one class and distinguish based on how that's been set (a little unusual in web api, but that's what [`ServiceStack`](http://www.servicestack.net/) does
4. Change your routing to always include the action name.

I can't really say what's best without understanding your exact scenario better;  Though personally I'd avoid the trickiness of getting all those arguments and simultaneous routes working on multiple actions - either always be explicit about the action, or address any possible message in code (i.e. options 3 or 4).  Complex routes in the face of optional arguments are simply a pain.

Comment: Hi, my goal was to implement the routing so that the client can call the controller without passing the parameter for the save -> "localhost:6850/Patient/save. The "save controller" is one option, but i would like to keep the functionality in one class, even if it doesn't fit in to REST world. About the routing, is there a way to specify it so that my current interface would work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that i have to modify my routing...

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API_2",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{not_used}",
    defaults: new { not_used = "-1" },
    constraints: new { action = "save|reset" });

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API_1",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{index}",
    defaults: new { action = "EMPTY", index = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

...and add the ActionName-attribute to all methods:

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("EMPTY")]
public IEnumerable<Patient> All()

[HttpGet, ActionName("EMPTY")]
public Patient ByIndex(int index)

[HttpPost, ActionName("EMPTY")]
public HttpResponseMessage Add([FromBody]Patient patient)

[HttpPost, ActionName("save")]
public void Save(int not_used = -1)
```

After those modifications, i can call the save like this:

```
localhost:6850/Patient/save
```