# Controller with multiple actions - wrong action called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller with two POST methods:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/api/controller/action1")]
[ActionName("action1")]
public HttpResponseMessage MethodA(string s1, string s2);

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/api/controller/action2")]
[ActionName("action2")]
public HttpResponseMessage MethodB(string s1, InternalClass c);
```

I'm calling it from a test harness. When I try to `POST` to `MethodB` using the URL `http://localhost/api/controller?s1=<string>`, passing `c` in the body of the POST, the message indicates that it's trying to call MethodA instead (I have a validation filter that indicates "s1 and s2 are required fields").

When I add the action to the URL and try to `POST` to `MethodB` using `http://localhost/api/controller/action2?s1=<string>`, passing `c` in the body, I get a 404 instead.

I modified my `RouteConfig` to use these routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Name1",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Name2",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: null,
  constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Name3",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

as was indicated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407267/multiple-httppost-method-in-mvc4-web-api-controller).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to POST to MethodB using the URL `http://localhost/api/controller?s1=<string>`, passing c in the body of the POST, the message indicates that it's trying to call MethodA instead (I have a validation filter that indicates "s1 and s2 are required fields").

It sounds like you're trying to rely on overloading to disambiguate your routes -- MVC doesn't work like this. You have to make sure your routes are defined to be unique, with a single `POST` and `GET` per route.

In this case, the default action method for `/api/controller` is `MethodA`, and it's trying to force object `C` into the second parameter of `MethodA`.

If you want the default to go to `MethodB`, you will have to update your route. However, it sounds like you want it to be dynamic and figure out the route based on the parameters being posted, and it doesn't work like that.

Also, this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Looks wrong, because it's pointing to the `Default` controller, `Index` action method, which you don't have listed in your code. So going to `api/controller` will try to go to `Default.Index`.

Lastly, consider the order of your routes. When the MVC pipeline evaluates your routes, it will match the first possible route. In your case, you have the more generic routes at the top, with the more specific routes at the bottom. You need to reorder these, putting the more specific routes at the top. [This article](http://www.freddes.se/2009/12/09/the-importance-of-the-order-of-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/) talks about this.

Comment: So I can't disambiguate by using the actions?

Comment: Yes, but not the parameters. Using the actions in the URL should work. What happens if you hard-code your routes, having two actions, one for each method? It sounds like you have something else wrong (outside of the code you've listed), so need to troubleshoot more.

Comment: I'll try hardcoding these routes now. But does the order of the routes matter? If I moved "Name3" (with controller and action) above "Name1" (with just controller), would it take precedence?

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. It's matching that second route. I would get rid of that one for now.

Comment: Actually, never mind, that route should not be matching, with the constraint. That's the point of the constraint.

Comment: I reordered the routes to move "Name1" below "Name2" and "Name3", and now the system is taking the Action into account. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome, I'll update the answer for future reference of others.