# Web API actions to be distinguishable only by their parameter types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Web API, how can I get two actions, both routed for the same URL and same HTTP method, to be distingushable only by their different parameter types?

I'd like to be able to `POST` either a single JSON object or a JSON array of objects.

I'm expecting it to work like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual object Post([FromBody]IDictionary<string, object> values)
{
    //add new object to collection
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual IEnumerable<object> Post([FromBody] IDictionary<string, object>[] array)
{
    return array.Select(Post);
}
```

However, if I do this and attempt to call either actions, I get this error:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request
```

Comment: May be this could be a help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407267/multiple-httppost-method-in-web-api-controller

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [attribute routing](http://attributerouting.net/#defining-routes) library. This allows you to define routes for each action in your web api. This has even been packaged as part of Web Api 2.0:

```
[POST("First URL here")]
public virtual object Post([FromBody]IDictionary<string, object> values)
{
    //add new object to collection
}

[POST("Second URL here")]
public virtual IEnumerable<object> Post([FromBody] IDictionary<string, object>[] array)
{
    return array.Select(Post);
}
```

This way you will be able to manually define your routes for each method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention I'd like them to be the same URL too (updated the question). Otherwise I could just set up another route in the `WebApiConfig.cs`.

Comment: Note that attribute routing is built into Web Api 2 itself