# web api multiple post methods with different parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Can I have 2 post methods with different datatypes as below :-

```
[HttpPost]        
public HttpResponseMessage Post([StringBody]string data)
{
   // Logic
}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Requirements objRequirement)
{ 
  //Logic
}
```

I am getting below error in postman :-

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Post(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) on type ATL.Trebuchet.RestApi.Controllers.ValuesController
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Post(ATL.Trebuchet.RestApi.Models.Requirements) on type ATL.Trebuchet.RestApi.Controllers.ValuesController</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Please help how can have same Post method with different type of parameters

I am sending data as `Text (text/plain)`

**EDIT 1 :**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use multiple post method in the same controller you need to map them to different routes or actions

For **Web api 1**

Add the route to the WebApiConfig, You can look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407267/multiple-httppost-method-in-web-api-controller) for details but the important thing is to specify that the default route api/controller/id only accepts integers. Else the actions will be treated as string ids.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
);
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Then in the controller specify the action ontop of the method

```
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]  
    [ActionName("post1")]      
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([StringBody]string data)
    {
       // Logic
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("post2")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Requirements objRequirement)
    { 
      //Logic
    }
}
```

For **Web api 2**

Here you can use Attribute Routing

```
[RoutePrefix("api/data")]
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]  
    [Route("post1")]      
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([StringBody]string data)
    {
       // Logic
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("post2")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Requirements objRequirement)
    { 
      //Logic
    }
}
```

The first post method will be called as api/data/post1 and the second api/data/post2

Comment: Not supporting routePrefix .. its telling me to add new class.. see edit1

Comment: Generate class for Route : same thing for [Route("")]

Comment: sorry, Didnt see you were using web api 1. In web api 2 you can use attribute routing which my solution is based on

Comment: Is there any solution for Web api 1 ??

Comment: same error with url :- http://localhost:57578/api/Values/PostString  Note:- PostString :- ActionName > [ActionName("PostString")]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407267/multiple-httppost-method-in-web-api-controller

Comment: @CSharper Do you have more routes added in the WebApiConfig class? If you have the default "api/{controller}/{id}" you need to add the constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } to it. Else the action will be treated as a id parameter

Comment: Done...thanks for your great help.. I commented my default route and it worked..!!!