# Web API is not working through URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have 3 WEB API and 2 of them are working. The third one is not working although it is similar the other ones.

**My Controller:**

```
public class LNAXController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<State> States()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return db.States.Where(s => s.Country.Code == "USA").OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<State> States(string countryCode)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return db.States.Where(s => s.Country.Code == countryCode).OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities(int stateId)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return db.Cities.Where(c => c.State.Id == stateId).OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The first and second API, return result using following urls I type in browser:

```
http://localhost:58211/api/lnax/states
http://localhost:58211/api/lnax/states/USA
```

But the 3rd one returns error when I use this url:  http://localhost:58211/api/lnax/cities/5

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58211/api/lnax/cities/5'.
>
> No action was found on the controller 'LNAX' that matches the request.

Edit:

This is my configuration code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit `Route` and playing around with it?  Perhaps try `[Route("/api/lnax/cities/{state}/")]`

Comment: If I use Route attribute, it will work, but I don't want to do that and want to make it work w/o attribute

Comment: It could be because the `5` is considered a `string`.  Try change your method signature to `public IEnumerable<City> Cities(string stateId)` and just see if it hits it.

Comment: Check out some of the examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407267/multiple-httppost-method-in-web-api-controller

Comment: no change when I use string type instead of int. let me read the link you sent

Comment: I used ActionName attribute but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your configuration, the problem is the name of parameter.

In your configuration you have `id` as parameter but in your method you have `stateId`, so you need to use the parameter transformation

Change your method signature as:

```
public IEnumerable<City> Cities([FromUri(Name = "id")]int stateId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have configured the Web API routing something like like:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{countryCode}",
            defaults: new { countryCode = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You have to let it know that you want to assign `countryCode` to `stateId`.
You could use `[FromUri]` attribute to the argument:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<City> Cities([FromUri(Name ="countryCode")]int stateId)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        return db.Cities.Where(c => c.State.Id == stateId).OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting answer. Please look at my edit. I post the configuration code.