# ASP.NET MVC Web.Api Routing - Real world example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have been looking at routing in the Web.Api and looking at various ways of representing endpoints. I came across [Instagrams REST endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/). (which has some lovely documentation) Using the Web.Api what would be the best way to set up the routing and controllers for a sitution like Instagrams user endpoints?

```
User Endpoints
GET/users/user-id                  Get basic information about a user.
GET/users/self/feed                See the authenticated user's feed.
GET/users/user-id/media/recent     Get the most recent media published by a user.
GET/users/self/media/liked         See the authenticated user's list of liked media.
GET/users/search                   Search for a user by name.
```

If I wanted to replicate these endpoints in my app, how would I go about it. Would I just need one controller 'Users' with 5 methods, what kind of routing would I need to direct the REST calls to those methods?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  Is this a quiz?

Comment: @RobertHarvey not a quiz, see edited question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would structure this in a different way.

```
GET/user
GET/user/user-id
GET/user?q=user-name

GET/media
GET/media/user-id
GET/media/user-id?selection=recent
GET/media/user-id?selection=liked

GET/feed
GET/feed/user-id
```

This way you keep your Controllers for a specific target, much like keeping your classes for a single responsibility.

- User
- Media
- Feed

When you use this approach it's much easier for a user to 'guess' the path. And I think you could already guess what each path does without any explanation. For me that's the most important when I'm designing a API.

```
GET/controller            - always returns a item list
GET/controller/id         - always returns a specific item
GET/controller?q=         - always queries the controller
GET/controller?selection= - always selects a subset from the list off items
```

Ofcourse this is open for interpretation but it gives you an idea about how I would solve this particular problem and maybe some ideas to think about. Also have a look at this great book from `Apigee - Web Api Designs`

http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf

**Edit:**

To make the routes you named I think you've got 2 (not very ideal) options.

1. Map a specific route for each  url
2. Make a wildcard route

**Option 1**
I have not tried, or used this myself but you can find more info here:

[Single controller with multiple GET methods in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api)

**Option 2**
If you go the wildcard route all requests with additional parameters will be routed to your default `Get()` method. In your get you have to look at the parameters using `ControllerContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath` or something like it and choose your actions on it.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "MyApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{*wildcard}",
     defaults: new { controller = "index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Comment: +1 Looks like a good book, thanks for that link. Your clarification of how to structure the api makes sense, I wonder why they didn't do that? However I am still interested in the routing that would be required using the Asp.Net Web.Api to get those routes.

Comment: That book is excellent. So nice and simple to read and so clear and defined.

Comment: I guess this leads to another question, when you map a specific route to a specific controller action, does the convention (and mapping) GetAction, PostAction, DeleteAction etc. still apply?

Comment: @AranMulholland I think so, since you add a `HttpMethodConstraint` for `HttpMethod.Get` or Put etc. to the route, but as I said I did never really go this route myself.

Comment: Excellent short book. Good suggestion.