# Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a problem with web api.I have wrote this action in my `LoginsController` for Web api.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string loginDetail(Login obj)
    {
        Login email = db.Logins.Find(obj.email);
        if (email == null)
        {
            return null;
        }


        Login detail = db.Logins.Find(obj.email);
        if (detail.password.Equals(obj.password))
        {
            string type = detail.type;
            return type;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }`
```

This is my LoginsController

`
        // GET: api/Logins
        public IQueryable GetLogins()
        {
            return db.Logins;
        }

```
    // GET: api/Logins/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Login))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLogin(string id)
    {
        Login login = db.Logins.Find(id);
        if (login == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(login);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string loginDetail(Login obj)
    {
        Login email = db.Logins.Find(obj.email);
        if (email == null)
        {
            return null;
        }


        Login detail = db.Logins.Find(obj.email);
        if (detail.password.Equals(obj.password))
        {
            string type = detail.type;
            return type;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // PUT: api/Logins/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutLogin(string id, Login login)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != login.email)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(login).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!LoginExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Logins
    [ResponseType(typeof(Login))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostLogin(Login login)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Logins.Add(login);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (LoginExists(login.email))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = login.email }, login);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Logins/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Login))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteLogin(string id)
    {
        Login login = db.Logins.Find(id);
        if (login == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Logins.Remove(login);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(login);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool LoginExists(string id)
    {
        return db.Logins.Count(e => e.email == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

}
`when i want to send an http post method to "/api/Logins/loginDetail" this error appears:`

> "Multiple actions were found that match the request: loginDetail on type Schoolmngt.Controllers.LoginsController
>   PostLogin on type Schoolmngt.Controllers.LoginsController"`

this is `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi3",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: What is the second action you have in controller, can you add that in question too

Comment: The error is clear enough that two methods have the same name so it does not know which to choose. That is not  allowed.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14534618/5358389

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest to use Attribute Route. For example, you can name your Action method like this,

```
[Route("Login")]
[HttpPost]
public string loginDetail(Login obj)
{
 ...
}
```

For more info, please see this one. I think this will solve your issue.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291025/multiple-actions-were-found-that-match-the-request-web-api)