# WebAPI Url match Issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I had implement AttributeRouting and WebApi in my web project.
And I try to route a Url like `http://localhost/apis/test?adminId=yyy` to `GetSomeInfo` Action. But I encounter some trouble , the url `http://localhost/apis/test` and `http://localhost/apis/test?adminId=yyy` both route to Action `GetEntity`. It seems it doesn't recognize the parameter `adminId`, It thought there is no parameters in url. So It turns out go to `GetEntity` Action. Can anyone help me? thanks.

What I had done so far is looks like below, It doesn't work.

```
[RoutePrefix("apis/test")]
public class SampleController : ApiController
{


    [HttpGet]
    [GET("")]
    public string GetEntity([FromUri]string name = null, [FromUri]string id = null)
    {
        ....
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [GET("")]
    public string GetSomeInfo([FromUri]string adminId)
    {
        ....
    }

 }
```

**Edited**

The route map code in `global.asax` is below. and I found the Url `http://localhost/api/Sample?adminId=2BD48CF9-95EB-48D2-A1B2-1AFA273E586D` can be routed to the `GetSomeInfo` Action. The Url `http://localhost/api/Sample` without any parameters route to `GetEntity`. that is exactly what I want. My question is why the `RoutePrefix` and `FromUri` doesn't work?

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

Comment: What is the issue? Have you got an error?

Comment: @k0stya Sorry for mistaking something . I had updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Because, you need to define further routes in global.asax.cs. see this, [Single controller with multiple GET methods in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Hi, Pitchai, Firstly please review my updated Post. And in my application, I used the `RoutePrefix` to match the url. Seems your mentioned solution is not in my case. thanks.

Comment: Then, you can add route constraints to GetSomeInfo method like this: [GET("url/{id}")]. Now this will respond to , /url/1 (via GET)

Comment: Thanks, But In my question, I don't know how to respond to the `/url?1`. Is it possible to make that ?