# Multiple GET actions in webApi Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I know this question have been asked many times before. But I have some different problem.

[Single controller with multiple GET methods in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api/12185249#12185249)

I have already followed the steps provided in the post on above link, but my api link is in format of api/servicename/controller.

And the routes given in the post is api/controller format. Could any one please help in getting this sorted out. I actually replced the routes with the exact name of my service but of no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, instead of writing routes as api/controller/action, I wrote it in the way given below. I got the code block from the link http://lonetechie.com/2013/03/04/fixing-multiple-actions-were-found-that-match-the-request-aspnet-webapi/ which then points to the link I have given in the original post.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "{controller}/{action}", new { action = "Get" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPut", "{controller}", new { action = "Put" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Put) });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiDelete", "{controller}", new { action = "Delete" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Delete) });
```