# Generic Web API Routing for Get "All" - WebAPI v1

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to create a route that will be handled by each of my controller's GetAll method vs. the paged, default Get method so that the url looks like the following: "api/{controller}/all"

```
    public class MyController {
        public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetAll() {
            ...
        }
        public IEnumerable<MyModel> Get(int page = 0, int pageSize = 50) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public class MyOtherController {
        public IEnumerable<MyOtherModel> GetAll() {
            ...
        }
        public IEnumerable<MyOtherModel> Get(int page = 0, int pageSize = 50) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

My routes looks like this currently:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: ControllerOnlyRoute,
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: ControllerAndIdRoute,
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: null
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: ControllerActionRoute,
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
```

I'm not sure how to create a route for each controller that will route to the GetAll method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Attribute routing](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/) nuget package for this. It makes setting up your routing a lot easier and even comes as part of WebApi 2. The documentation for it can be found [here](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting).

Comment: As an alternative, this solution also works (and was what I ultimately went with rather than Attribute Routing):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api