# How multiple Get function could be there in a web api controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

just see the scenario

```
 public class CustomerController : ApiController
 {
     public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByID(int id)
     {

     }

     public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByName(string name)
     {

     }

     public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByEmail(string strEmail)
     {

     }
 }
```

now tell me what i need to do as a result end user can call three get action by their name. how to handle this situation. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set route for each method. Such as:

```
 [Route("GetById/{id}")]
 public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByID(int id)
 {

 }
```

You can call it `getbyid/3`. More details [web api routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Also there is a question for this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api).