# ASP.NET WebAPI Get overloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to have multiple `Get` methods with the same number of parameters? For example, I would like to have a `Get(int)` and a `Get(string)`. I've tried experimenting with this, but it always seems to hit the `Get(string)` method and never the one with the `int`. So is it possible to make these two distinguishable?

Comment: Internally in the code base you can, but I've found it best to apply the `Route` attribute to the overloaded methods to define a different URL signature.

Comment: Not sure if it's doable but try casting the input to int?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: `Get` method itself will not be used by developers(only in tests maybe). So I think more descriptive name will be more readable approach in case of API controller's method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it but you have to specify different routes for each Get method.