# How to manage multiple actions on same route when trying to access HttpDelete

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, webapi, restful-url

I have problem with managing multiple actions on same route when trying to access HttpDelete controller method.

```
[Route("api/doctors/{id}/{type}")]
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Toggle(int id, string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "delete":
            return Ok(await Delete(id));
        case "disable":
            return Ok(await Disable(id));
        case "block":
            return Ok(await Block(id));
        default:
            return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Like this, I am using verbs in the route, but I like to avoid them.
Can somebody tell me better way to manage them?

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: @J.Salas I like to try to avoid using verbs in the routes. As I know using verbs in routes is bad practice in RESTful API.

Comment: I think you aren't,  type seems a 'delete' method switch.  (physical record delete), (just mark record as deleted) (just mark record as deleted for everyone but  administrator)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one -> [Single controller with multiple GET methods in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api)

It is about HttpGet but I think you will get the same idea.